# Form Game, string error? (vs2015desktop)

Tags: c#, winforms, text

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Treasure_Hunter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
```

The problem is here

```
        private void Axe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string aaxe = "n";

        if (aaxe = = 'y');
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("You Used your AXE");
        }   
        else    
        {    
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Empty");
        }
```

what I'm trying to do is have it do is to check for "aaxe = y/n" and if it is yes(y) it will work other wise say "Empty"

ERRORS

Error   CS1525  Invalid expression term '=' Treasure Hunter     23

Warning CS0642  Possible mistaken empty statement   Treasure Hunter     23

Error   CS1513  } expected  Treasure Hunter     26

```
        }

        private void Pickaxe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Shovel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Candle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Knife_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Key_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Treasure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a treasure hunting text game.

Comment: after that i got a new error 'CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char'

Comment: Spaces matter... also, listen to your compiler. Finally, even with that working you won't ever get into your "y" block, just something to consider. To your edited comment... keep listening to your compiler.

Comment: try changing 'y'  to "y" (double quotes). single quotes and double quotes are different as well

Comment: if (aaxe = = 'y'); No semicolon

Comment: if (aaxe == "y") it should be like this

Comment: You need to start very slow. Please try making a very simple console application. Then progress to using classes. Then start working on GUI.  At this rate, you are going to spend all of your time on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have been making simples console apps by watching nerdgasm and then i got to the simple web browser. so i thought i should try a text adventure

Comment: And it works thanks guys!

Comment: If anyone is still looking is there anyway to make the aaxe string useable somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This part of the code will always be false:

```
private void Axe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string aaxe = "n";
    if (aaxe == ('y').ToString())
    {
       ...
```

Aaxe needs to be declared at the class level

Also why is there a space '= =' in your code, instead of '=='

Comment: this is wrong remove the semicolon on the if statement

Comment: And also has a compiler error on the comparison...

Comment: You're both right.  My bad :)

Comment: You can't compare a string with a char. It will generate a compile error. `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char'`